# bash completion does not work for newly added user

Tags: bash, shell

I added a new user in my ubuntu system with

```
sudo useradd -d /home/peeyush -m peeyush
sudo passwd peeyush
```

The above list of commands created a new user successfuly but the new user is unable to use the feature of bash completion properly. Using the bashrc file solved the problem.

This problems generally don't occur with traditional create user GUI. What is the reason behind this ?? Do they set the default shell for this user as bash ??

Comment: there is an ubuntu site in SE: http://askubuntu.com/ maybe you should ask there instead

Comment: the question is not specific to ubuntu

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: it's not a programming question, so off-topic on Stack Overflow. (And useradd/default user settings are indeed distro-specific.)

Comment: @Mat "Not a programming question" may be a valid reason to move the question but your point that user settings are distro specific is incorrect reson to close it. I am asking questions about basic command utilities and the mention of a distro Ubuntu in the question is not a valid reason for you to close / vote down a question. I asked the question because I did not know about the thing properly.

Comment: There's [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: I didn't vote down your post. I voted to migrate it here. As you'll notice, my comment about distro-specific things is in parenthesis, meaning additional information which I thought you might find useful.

Comment: "unable to use the feature of bash completion properly" isn't enough information. *How* does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the new user's default skeleton rc files were not created. You can specify that on creation with the `-k SKELETONDIR` option to `useradd`, where `SKELETONDIR` is usually `/etc/skel`.

And you should also check what is the default shell for the new user (and change it to `/bin/bash` if necessary - see `man chsh`).

If it's `bash`, add this to his `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. the skeleton directory was there from the beginning. So, I guess Ubuntu installation uses the same skel folder for new user creation.

Comment: The default shell bit is sneaky.